# How to define a range of u8 that can exhaust in pattern match

Tags: rust

```
#[derive(PartialEq, Eq)]
pub struct SlidingRole(u8);

const KING: SlidingRole = SlidingRole(1);
const QUEEN: SlidingRole = SlidingRole(2);

const ALL_SLIDING_ROLES: [SlidingRole; 2] = [
  KING,
  QUEEN
];

// error[E0004]: non-exhaustive patterns: `SlidingRole(0_u8)` and `SlidingRole(3_u8..=u8::MAX)` not covered
fn adf(role: SlidingRole) -> u8 {
    match role {
        KING => 3,
        QUEEN => 2
    }
}

fn main() {
    println!("Hello, world!");
}
```

Comment: Any particular reason `SlidingRole` isn't an enum?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This looks like a perfect use case for `enum`. Note that `enum` in Rust is not like it is in C. In C, `enum` is a narrow wrapper around an integer. In Rust, it's a full-fledged sum-of-product algebraic data type, capable of describing basically whatever you want.

```
#[derive(Clone, Copy)]
pub enum SlidingRole { King, Queen }

fn adf(role: SlidingRole) -> u8 {
  match role {
    SlidingRole::King => 3,
    SlidingRole::Queen => 2,
  }
}
```

Now `SlidingRole` is a new type with exactly two possible values. If you want, you can provide [`From`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/convert/trait.From.html) / [`TryFrom`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/nightly/core/convert/trait.TryFrom.html) instances for conversion to / from `u8`.

I also derive `Clone` and `Copy` so you don't have to worry about borrow semantics in the above example. For simple enums (where it's just a list of cases like yours is), this is fine. If your enum starts to contain something like a `String`, you won't be able to get `Copy` since it's no longer a plain memcpy to clone data. You'll probably want to add `Eq`, `PartialEq`, and potentially an ordering, depending on your specific use cases.

Finally, if you need the underlying representation to be `u8` (for instance, if you're interfacing with a C library), you can use a `repr` annotation to force this.

```
#[repr(u8)]
#[derive(Clone, Copy)]
pub enum SlidingRole { King, Queen }
```

Now `SlidingRole` is genuinely still a new type, distinct from `u8`. But it's guaranteed to use a memory layout equivalent to `u8`, so you can pass it to C functions expecting a `u8`, and you can `transmute` it to/from a `u8` safely. This is a niche and more advanced use case, so I don't recommend doing it unless you specifically *need* the data to be a `u8`.

In particular, you shouldn't do this for the purposes of premature optimization; Rust's compiler is already *really* good at optimizing datatypes, so "I think this fits best in `u8`" is not a good use case; the compiler is smarter than you or I when it comes to building assembly code. Stick with a plain `enum` unless you have a very niche use case.

Comment: Note that you can cast enums that just have unit variants to an integer with `as`, and also explicitly set the value of the variants, eg `enum SlidingRole{ King=3, Queen=2}`.